# Cannot Register the Replica Instance on Main Instance Console

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm trying to connect the REPLICA instance to MAIN Instance are in different server (server A, server B) and there I set up with the docker, here is the setup I have:

MG1 is the MAIN Instance
MG2 is configured as REPLICA with

```
SET REPLICATION ROLE TO REPLICA WITH PORT 10000;
```

The next step would be to connect the main to replicas, which I'm trying to do with (executed on the main)

```
REGISTER REPLICA r1 ASYNC TO "DNS:10000";
```

I was trying different ways:

```
memgraph> REGISTER REPLICA r1 ASYNC TO "IP";
memgraph> REGISTER REPLICA r1 ASYNC TO "IP:10000";
memgraph> REGISTER REPLICA r1 ASYNC TO "DNS:10000";
```

But I am getting an error:

> Client received query exception: Couldn't register replica 'r1'!

Moreover, I am using LAN and port are already configure correctly.

Any idea what I'm missing?